# Insert a value/Row in a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view which have like 4 Values,

---

```
   Element No        Details     UniqueID
         1           Alpha          2000
         2           Beta           2001
         3           Zeta           2002
         4           Gamma          2003
```

This is a view, and I am trying to insert another value at run time; on top of which I am gonna create another View.

---

```
   Element No        Details     UniqueID
         0           Pie            1000
         1           Alpha          2000
         2           Beta           2001
         3           Zeta           2002
         4           Gamma          2003
```

**EDIT:**

I have to add a value to the table with element No: 0 . The initial table is obtained when I run a view1. I am trying to create another view2 by using the present view1 and couple of other View and Tables. So i need to insert the above value into View1 to obtain my required value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
create view yourview2
as
select 0 as "Element No", 'Pie' as Details , 1000 as UniqueID
union all 
select [Element No], Details, UniqueID
from yourview
```

**NOTE**: `union all` doesn't remove duplicates

Comment: you may be better off going back to the original tables when creating the new view, as opposed to hitting the existing view....you'll suffer a pretty significant performance hit going through a view to generate a second view.

Comment: @user2366842 I don't know why OP want to create a view.

Comment: This is just a part of the query I am writing where The original view does not have the value needed for me to populate in a Parent View. I Cant insert it into the table directly as it is a calculated value that only needs to available during the run time of the query.